# EntityFramework Invalid Column Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

UPDATE: Matching both datatypes of BasketID to int does not resolve the issue.

**Code causing the error:**

```
 BasketItem duplicateBasketItem = (from thisitem in storeDB.BasketItems
                                   where thisitem.sellerSKU == newItem.sellerSKU
                                   select thisitem).SingleOrDefault();
```

**The error being thrown:**

*An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code*

**{"Invalid column name 'BasketID'."}**

**My Models:**

```
public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public int  BasketID { get; set; }
    public List<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}


public class BasketItem
{
    public int BasketItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual string BasketID { get; set; }
    public int sellerID { get; set; }
    public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class StoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItems> OrderItems {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Basket> Basket { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this will solve the issue, but in `BasketItem` you have `public virtual string BasketID { get; set; }` but `BasketId` is an int in the `Basket` class

Comment: I'm guessing your `BasketItems` table is missing the `BasketID` column?

Comment: Can you show your tables? What have you used Code First, reverse engineer Code First?

Answer (score 0):

What this error message is telling you that there is an error in your bindings, or that there is no such column in database table. I can see that `BasketID` in `BasketItem` is string, so that is one error right there, change it to `int` and see how it goes.

```
public class BasketItem

{
    public int BasketItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual int BasketID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

write int datatype instead of string for BasketId as shown below :-

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public int BasketItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual int BasketID { get; set; }
    public int sellerID { get; set; }
    public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

BasketId is int in Basket table but you have specified string in your BasketItem table so its not finding any relation between them . Try adding int datatype and try again!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix with a slight workaround by not accesing the db context directly

```
ShoppingBasket myBasket = new ShoppingBasket();
        myBasket.ShoppingBasketId = basketID;

        Basket storebasket = (from ph in storeDB.Basket
                                      where ph.BasketID == myBasket.ShoppingBasketId
                                      select ph).SingleOrDefault();
```