# EntityFrameWork SaveChanges Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make changes to a database by using Entity Framework (code-first). Everything works fine up until I attempt to save changes, when an error is thrown:

> Invalid Column Name BasketID

However, during debugging, looking at the `storeDB.BasketItems`, the `basketitem` was actually added.

What am I missing ?

Code:

```
// Basket is ENTIRELY Empty, add new item and move on.
if (storebasket == null || storebasket.BasketItems.Count == 0)
{
   // Add item as is
   BasketItem newItem = new BasketItem
              {
                sellerSKU = basketItem.sellerSKU,
                BasketID = basketID,
                sellerID = 1,
                Quantity = basketItem.Quantity,
                Price = basketItem.Price
              };

   storeDB.BasketItems.Add(newItem);
   storeDB.SaveChanges();
}
```

Database entity:

```
public class StoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Basket> Basket { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Basket
{
    [Key]
    public string BasketID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}

public class BasketItem
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual string BasketID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int sellerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**OP pasted Edit as Answer:**

I have no idea why this fixed the problem, but the program works as expected now

```
public StoreEntities(): base("storeDBConnectionString") 
 {
     Database.SetInitializer<StoreEntities>(
           new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<StoreEntities>());
```

Comment: [One question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627792/entityframework-invalid-column-name) [is enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640197/entityframework-one-to-many-fk).

Comment: This is actually a different question. The other errors were resolved and would not even make it that far into the code. Thanks.

Comment: Then accept the answers or provide one on them. The way you resolved that issue may very well help you towards fixing this one.

Comment: Is `BasketID` an actual column?

Answer (score 0):

If you Look at your BasketItem class you set your BasketID as virtual... That causes entity framework not to bind the property to a column. The correct way to do it would be :

```
public class BasketItem
{
[Key]
public int BasketItemID { get; set; }

public virtual Basket Basket { get; set; }

public string BasketID { get; set; }

[Required]
public int sellerID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string sellerSKU { get; set; }
[Required]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
[Required]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```